# Netcat output pipe, json parsing

Tags: bash, pipe, netcat

What I want is this:

- netcat to the server, which streams json formatted loglines.
- pipe the output of nc to "something" that will format the json as plaintext, in a customizable format (thinking something like perl or python here).
- allow "something" to be greppable.

My small attempts at piping the output of nc to something else leads to the server outputting "Broken pipe".

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Would parsing the JSON be acceptable or do you prefer to grep?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start looking at the python JSON processors, to start you can format it in "pretty" style simply:

`| python -mjson.tool`

and there are many people who have extended on that, here are a [few](https://github.com/nicksieger/jsonpretty) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-to-pretty-print-json-from-the-command-line).

Comment: This one worked really nice and would be a good starting point on formatting the output. As stated in another comment, the issue I'm having is something that I suspect has to do with nc.

Comment: Yeah, remember all JSON is not created equal.

Answer (score 1):

I use [jq](http://stedolan.github.com/jq/) to parse JSON on the command line.  I'm aware that your question asks for something to render it in plaintext for grepping, but I think this is closer to what you're trying to accomplish.

For instance:

```
{"chef_server": 
    {
    "server_url": "http://localhost:4000"
    },"run_list": 
        [ 
        "recipe[apt::default]",
        "recipe[build-essential::default]",
        "recipe[chef-server::rubygems-install]" 
        ]
    }
```

Can be parsed to yield:

```
    tristan.local]$  ~  cat chef.json| jq -c '.run_list[]' 
    "recipe[apt::default]"
    "recipe[build-essential::default]"
    "recipe[chef-server::rubygems-install]"
```

Check out the [tutorial](http://stedolan.github.com/jq/tutorial/), it's quite useful.

Comment: Neat tool! Although I suspect that this won't work with a nc pipe (see my edit)

Comment: Ah, track down why you're getting disconnected when trying to stream data first.